# How do i stop my list overlapping my header image?

Tags: html, css, list, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I have a website I'm building, i'm using Skeleton CSS and everything is responsive and works fine.

i have a menu bar (list) in the correct place, but when I resize, it seems to overlap my header image, does anybody know how I can stop this?

Example here: http://www.cosworth-europe.co.uk/test/indextest.html

Please resize your browser down.

HTML:

```
    <div id="top"><center><img src="images/header.png" style="max-width:100%;"></center></div>
<header id="header" class="site-header" role="banner">
<div id="header-inner" class="container sixteen columns over">
<hgroup class="one-third column alpha">

</hgroup>
    <nav id="main-nav" class="two thirds column omega">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="about-us.html">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="news.html">News</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="dealers.html">Dealers</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="products.html">Products</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.cosworth-europe.co.uk/shop">Buy Online</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

</div>

</header>
```

CSS:

```css
#top {background-image: url(../images/header-gradient.gif);
 background-repeat: repeat-x; 
 max-width:100%;
 height:110px;}

#header {margin-top: -5px; margin-bottom: 30px;}
h1 a { text-indent: -9999px; }
#site-title { padding-top: 10px;}

#main-nav { 
    position:absolute;
    right:120px;
    bottom:0px; 
}

#main-nav ul, #main-nav li {display: inline; padding: 7px;}
#main-nav a {text-decoration:none; color: black;}
```

Comment: Could we see what your site looks like, and a comparison of the css you changed versus the css of the original?

Comment: You're setting a static value for the 'right' property of #main-nav. That's not very responsive. As your screen shrinks, it's always going to try to be 120px from the right. You should change that value to be a percentage, or find some way to make it scale with window size.

Comment: Theres a link above Connor ^^

Comment: ahh I see @Eric Guan, I removed the static value and replaced it with 'float:right;' which has solved the issue - but I can't use padding to move it around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use media queries to deal with how elements are positioned depending on the different sizes. You are using position: absolute for the #main-nav which is fixing the navigation bar in place, regardless of the screen size.

Example:

CSS:

```
#main-nav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 120px; /* Default */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    body {  
        #main-nav {
            position: absolute;
            right: 50px; /* Will apply when the screens width is smaller than 700px */
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your nav is absolutely positioned. Depending on what you want to happen to it, I'd probably add some media queries to into the correct place.

I'd probably move the header image left a little and nudge the nav right - that'l only work until a certain size though, after that you'll need a different layout for the nav bar.